# Save list object in database with binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

So i am new to entity framework. I have a problem saving a list into the database.

Create method in controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("NieuwsArtikelID,titel,datum,imgNaam")] NieuwsArtikel nieuwsArtikel,
        [Bind("blog.inleiding", "blog.inleidingTitel")] Blog blog, [Bind("blog.alinea[i].AlineaTitel", "blog.alinea[i].AlineaTekst")] List<Alinea> alineas)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            nieuwsArtikel.blog = blog;
            nieuwsArtikel.blog.alineas = alineas;
            _context.Add(nieuwsArtikel);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(nieuwsArtikel);
    }
```

Saving the blog data in the database works just fine, but saving the alinea data won't work. It probably doesn't work because it's a list. The question is than: how can i save a list object in the database?

NieuwsArtikel class:

```
public class NieuwsArtikel
{  
    public int NieuwsArtikelID { get; set; }
    public string titel { get; set; }
    public string datum { get; set; }
    public Blog blog { get; set; }
    public string imgNaam { get; set; }
}
```

Blog class:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogID {get; set;}
    public string inleidingTitel { get; set; }
    public string inleiding { get; set; }

    public List<Alinea> alineas { get; set; }
}
```

Alinea class:

```
public class Alinea
{
    public int AlineaID { get; set; }
    public string AlineaTitel { get; set; }
    public string AlineaTekst { get; set; }
    public string AlineaQuote { get; set; }
    public string AlineaFoto { get; set; }

    public int BlogForeignKey { get; set; }
    public Blog blog { get; set; }
}
```

Create view:

```
<form asp-action="Create">
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>NieuwsArtikel</h4>
    <hr />
    <!--Alinea begin-->
    @for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="blog.alineas[i].AlineaTitel" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input asp-for="blog.alineas[i].AlineaTitel" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="blog.alineas[i].AlineaTitel" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="blog.alineas[i].AlineaTekst" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input asp-for="blog.alineas[i].AlineaTekst" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="blog.alineas[i].AlineaTekst" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
    }
    <!-- Alinea eindig-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have only put in the Alinea form groups to make it more readable.

Comment: Your assumption _"It probably doesn't work because it's a list"_ is incorrect. People have been saving lists of child entities using Entity Framework for years. Read [ask] and debug your code. What does `alineas` contain? What do you mean _exactly_ by _"saving the alinea data won't work"_? What do you expect to happen, what actually happens?

Comment: Get rid of all those crazy `[Bind]` attributes. You method just needs to be `public async Task<IActionResult> Create(NieuwsArtikel model)`

Comment: And do not use `@for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)` - you use `@for (int i = 0; i <Model.alineas.Count; i++)` and you populate the the model with 2 items if that what you want to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        nieuwsArtikel.blog = blog;
        nieuwsArtikel.blog.alineas = alineas;
        _context.Add(nieuwsArtikel);

        foreach (Aliena a in alienas)
        {
            _context.Add(a);
        }

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(nieuwsArtikel);
```

Now, if the Aliena objects need a foreign key reference, you have to save them separately since you won't know the ID of the nieuwsArtikel object until later (if you're using Identity columns in the database). If you're not, just change it to:

```
a.foreign_key_property_here = nieuwsArtikel.primary_key_property_here
```

before calling add. That should do it just fine.

There are other alternatives. For instance, you could use user-defined tables in SQL, and use a stored procedure to send both sets of data at once. Then you can use an OUTPUT clause to output your foreign key references and save the aliena records in the same transaction. Or you can pass the aliena as XML to the stored proc and save them that way.

Comment: _"you have to save them separately"_ - Entity Framework handles that for you. As for the UDT, SP and XML approach: no, just no. That beats the entire purpose of using an ORM.